# Enforce single instance of electron app on Windows, but make a launcher click open new window

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to enforce a Single Instance for my electron app. When a user clicks the app shortcut icon on Windows, I want to enforce the single instance, but still open up a new window on the main instance when this happens.

All other current solutions seem to just quit the new instance and refocus the current instance.

```
  const singleInstanceLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
  if (!singleInstanceLock) { 
    app.exit();
  } else {
    app.focus();
  }

  app.on('second-instance', (_event: Electron.Event, argv: string[]) => { 
     app.focus();   
     // code to open up second window lives here. As far as I can tell, it doesnt get called
  });
```

Comment: Hi, so just to be clear there should only be one instance at a time, but can have multiple windows. And when the user tries to open another instance the instance quits and the already open instance creates a new window?

Comment: Precisely. I've tried following the example here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#apprequestsingleinstancelock - where on the second instance, I open up a new window from the main instance. But for some reason this does not seem to be happening, an the app is exiting.

Comment: I see, when you say the app is exiting do you mean both instances are exiting, or the instance already open was exiting? Also would you mind including your `requestSingleInstanceLock` code?

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Comment: The instance already open is exiting, as is the new instance that is launched, so I end up with no launched instances after trying to launch the second instance

Comment: @Stuart: Did you find a solution. I too find that when the second launch happens it just quits and does not process the request. At least it should open the earlier instance and set focus

Answer (score 0):

`app.exit();` Is a more severe way of quitting an app which quits all the instances of Electron instead of just the current one.

Try using `app.quit()` instead.

Also, separately, I'd re-arrange your code so it's like this:

```
const singleInstanceLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!singleInstanceLock) { 
  app.quit();
} else {
  app.on('second-instance', (_event: Electron.Event, argv: string[]) => { 
     app.focus(); 
     // Code to open up second window goes here.
  });
}
```

Replacing your first `app.focus()` with the `app.on('second-instance'`.

This is because you're running `app.requestSingleInstanceLock()` when the app first starts (as it should), but doing `app.focus()` wouldn't do anything since the app was only just opened, and there wouldn't be any windows to focus.

Comment: Made those changes. Both app instances are still quitting, so it must be something else that is triggering the initial, primary instance to also quit upon trying to open the second.

Comment: Adding tons of log statements on all paths that seem to possible quit the app, but I just cannot find out why it is closing.

Comment: @Stuart Huh, I don't know why it's quitting for you. Can you post your entire script? Or if too big just the relevant parts (window creation, instance lock, focus events, etc).